# What is the pdf of $Z=X/\max(X,Y)$ with $X,Y$ exponentials of lambda parameter?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution, actuarial-science

Given $X,Y$ 2 independent r.v.'s both distributed as $\exp(λ)$, what is the pdf of $Z=X/\max(X,Y)$?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Nice question for illustrating conditioning. **Given** the maximum is $X$ (probability $1/2$) then things are easy. Given the maximum is $Y$, note that the conditional distribution of $Y-X$, given $X$, is exponential with parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: I know $P(X>Y)=P(X<Y)=1/2$. Then, shouldn't i have $P(Z<z)=P(X<zX|X>Y)P(X>Y)+P(X<zY|Y>X)P(Y>X)$=$0+P(X<zY|Y>X)P(Y>X)$                                                   ?

Comment: Then i calculate $P(Z<z)=P(X<zy|Y=y)P(Y=y)$ and i get $P(Z<z)=z/(1+z)$. Do I still have to weight it by $P(Y>X)=1/2$? @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 0):

For $0 < t < 1$,
\begin{align}
P(Z < t) =& P(X < t \max(X,Y)) \\
=& P(Y>X \text{ and }X < tY) \\
=& P(X < tY) \\
=& \int_{0}^{+\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda y}(\int_{0}^{ty }\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx)dy \\
=& \frac{t}{1+t}
\end{align}

and $P(Z = 1) = P(X \geq Y) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Here we get the cdf, since it's not absolutely continuous with respect to the Borel measure, there is no pdf.